# How to install a django app in alwaysdata.com?

Tags: django, deployment

I've just singed for a free account at alwaysdata.com and I'd like to install a Django app. The problem is I don't know how to deploy it. The docs seem to be in french: http://wiki.alwaysdata.com/wiki/D%C3%A9ployer_une_application_Django

Do you know any guide in english or spanish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of the page you link to, it basically says "Just follow the instructions on the Django site" and gives you a link to [the FastCGI deployment docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#running-django-on-a-shared-hosting-provider-with-apache). The rest is just an example.